# DataOutputStream encodes wrong in Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I am trying out my Android app on http://requestb.in/ (this is a website that receives requests and displays it). However, my json is twisted into nonsense. This is my code

```
        string data = myJsonObject.ToString();
        URL url = new URL(intent.GetStringExtra("http://requestb.in/1buqtfe1"));
        URLConnection urlConn;
        DataOutputStream printout;

        urlConn = url.OpenConnection();
        urlConn.DoInput = true;
        urlConn.DoOutput = true;
        urlConn.UseCaches = false;
        urlConn.SetRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConn.Connect();

        printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.OutputStream);
        printout.WriteUTF(URLEncoder.Encode(data, "UTF-8"));
        printout.Flush();
        printout.Close();
```

(the link Im using is valid for about 48 hours for now, nothing sensitive).

%7B%0A++%22Trips%22%3A+%5B%0A++++%7B%0A++++++%22tripId%22%3A+%2220160614-135000-2099%22%2C%0A++++++%22beaconId%22%3A+%2200000000-0000-0000-0000-000000114099%22%2C%0A++++++%22user%22%3A+%22Marius%22%2C%0A++++++%22records%22%3A+6%2C%0A++++++%22created%22%3A+%222016-06-14+13-50-...

... and it should be Json. I found an "[online multi-decoder](http://2cyr.com/decode/)" website, and I was able to decode my json as WINDOWS-1251. Im not really sure whats going on here, I use the very same code in another Android app that is made in Android Studio, but when I run this same code in Visual Studio and Xamarin, this is my result. I have tried requests from Postman aswell, and they appear as correct json.

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong??

Comment: The encoding you're using isn't UTF-8, but rather Windows-1251. The code however seems to be forcing UTF-8, so... i don't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The text looks fro my perspective like an URL encoded JSON document. Where is the problem? The "strange characters" are because of the URL encoding.

Comment: Dear God.. Trying to decode it as url was what I was expecting to do, and it was the first thing I tried, however nothing would change. On closer inspection on my first attempts, it seems the strings for some reason starts with "%/%7B%0A++%22Trips%22%3A+%", and this slash (second character) was messing up the decoding. I dont know what I did in the beginning to get this slash there.. Its too late on the day apparently.